# Materialized Table with Indexes

Tags: postgresql, dbt

```
{{ config(
    materialized = 'table',
    indexes=[
      {'columns': ['column_a'], 'type': 'hash'},
      {'columns': ['column_a', 'column_b'], 'unique': True},
    ]
)}}

select ...
```

I am new to dbt and I am trying to understand the concept of Materialization (`view` vs `table`). i have read extensively on https://docs.getdbt.com/docs/build/materializations#view

But I am still struggling to find a good explanation as to why we need to use indexes with the materialized `table`. I found this documentation which did not help me much.

https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/resource-configs/postgres-configs

Can someone please comment and explain the code above?

Thank you for your help

Comment: Well you don't *need* to, but *being able* to build indices is usually the entire point of materialising a view

Comment: with the indexes queries against the materialzed view will be faster as the query can find the wanted rows faster

Comment: What do we actually mean by indexes? Usually there is a column index at the left of the table. But on the code above, i am seeing multiple indexes..,why is that?

Comment: You can read about indices in Postgres here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.1/indices.html

Comment: @Aleix CC   Thank you